# is there a way to change video resolution of any size to 720x1280 with fluent-ffmpeg without squeezing the video?

Tags: fluent-ffmpeg

I'm trying to convert any size video to 720x1280.

### Example of what I'm trying to achieve:

[image]

#### Errors I get:

- Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Conversion failed!
- Error: ffmpeg exited with code 1: Cannot find a matching stream for unlabeled input pad 0 on filter Parsed_scale_1

#### What I'm trying to do:

I'm trying to get 720x1280 video from a video with full height and no padding without squeezing the video itself.

#### What did I do:

```
ffmpeg()
    .input(inputPath)
    .toFormat("mp4")
    // .addOption("-vf", "scale=1920:-2,pad=1920:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2")
    // .addOption("-vf", "scale=720:-2,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2")
    // .addOption(
    //   "-vf",
    //   "scale=720:-2,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3"
    // )
    // .addOption(
    //   "-vf",
    //   "scale=720:-2,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3"
    // )
    // .videoCodec("libx264")
    .outputOptions(["-vf scale=720*sar:1080,setsar=1", "-s 720x1080"])
    
    // .outputOptions(["-vf scale=iw*sar:ih,setsar=1", "-s 720x1280"])
    // .size("720x1280")
    // .aspect("9:16")
    // .autoPad()
    .save(outputPath)
    .on("progress", (progress) => {
      console.log("Progress: ", Math.floor(progress.percent), progress);
    })
    .on("end", () => {
      console.log("finished");
    });
```

I also tried getting help from chatgpt but the code provided by chatgpt doesn't work.

#### Output I want:

[image]

Output I get with my code is either squeezed or its 720x1280 but the video is small and is in center

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve something similar with this:

```
'crop=720:ih:600:0,scale=720:-2,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2',
```

This is what you need:

```
ffmpeg()
.input(inputPath)
.toFormat("mp4")
.addOption(
  "-vf",
  "crop=720:ih:600:0,scale=720:-2,pad=720:1280:(ow-iw)/2:(oh-ih)/2,colorchannelmixer=.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3:0:.3:.4:.3"
)
.save(outputPath)
.on("progress", (progress) => {
  console.log("Progress: ", Math.floor(progress.percent));
})
.on("end", () => {
  console.log("finished");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i had the same issue as you so i tried modified the code and  the things done here is the code hope this works for you.
you can change the parameters according to your need.
'''python
import subprocess
import re

```
def get_video_dimensions(input_file):
    cmd = ['ffprobe', '-v', 'error', '-select_streams', 'v:0', '- 
    show_entries', 'stream=width,height', '-of', 'csv=s=x:p=0', input_file]
    output = subprocess.check_output(cmd, 
    stderr=subprocess.STDOUT).decode('utf-8').strip()
    dimensions = re.split('[x\n]', output)
    width = int(dimensions[0])
    height = int(dimensions[1])
    return width, height

def resize_and_pad(input_file, output_file):
   try:
      width, height = get_video_dimensions(input_file)
      pad_dimensions = f"{max(width, 720)}:{max(height, 1280)}"
      subprocess.run(['ffmpeg', '-i', input_file, "-vf", 
      f"crop=720:ih:600:0,scale=720:-2,pad={pad_dimensions}:(ow-iw)/2:(oh- 
      ih)/2", '-c:a', 'copy', output_file])
  except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
      print(f'Error trimming {input_file}: {e}')
  except Exception as e:
      print(f'Error: {e}')
```

'''

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).